# Getting the exponent of a floating number in C

Tags: c, floating-point, puzzle, exponent

So I am trying to return the exponent value for f.  If x is infinity or NaN I need to return Tmax. f is to be interpreted as the bit-level representations of single-precision floating point values and yes I mean to pass in an unsigned variable. I know I need to remove the appropriate value for the bias. I just cant figure out how. I can use any operations I want but only 8 of them (= does not count).

```
int float_exp(unsigned uf) {
    int mask = 2139095040;
    int hold;
    hold = uf & mask;
    if(mask == hold){
            return Tmax;
    } else {
        return ;// something here???
    }

}
```

I cant figure out how to get the exponent. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it wasn't for homework, you'd look up `frexp()` in your manual.

Comment: See also [Dividing floating point numbers by half in binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159484/dividing-floating-point-numbers-by-half-in-binary). Not a direct duplicate, but closely related.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your comments are not helping.

Comment: Why are you expressing a mask in decimal? Hex would make what you're doing much clearer, to your readers and to yourself.

Comment: bitwise operations should use hexadecimal masks since it relate directly to the binary encodings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number is denormalized subtract 127 from the exponent. If it is not then subtract 126.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it now.

Comment: @Cole Is it not the other way around, if the number is de-normalized, subtract 126.

Answer (score 2):

Check the floating point format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

The binary exponent is in bits 23  through 30.  So after masking against 0x7F800000, as you have done, you just need to shift what's left to the right by 23 bits and you have your binary exponent.

Then adjust for the bias, by subtracting it off.